# Regex: Email contain numbers but they are not on year pattern

Tags: regex, email, 2-digit-year

I'm new using regex and, after some tutorials, I'm getting difficult to implement an match criteria like "Email contain numbers but they are not on year pattern".

So, I have this simple regex for "contain numbers":

```
\d+(?=@)
```

Considering that e-mail address does have numbers, I would like to get a match for expressions NOT being in one of these below:

```
\w*(19|20)\d{2}\D*(?=@)
\w*[6-9][0-9]\D*(?=@)
\w*[0-1][0-9]\D*(?=@)
```

How, in regex, can I express this?

Example matching inputs:

```
foo123@gmail.com
a22oo@hotmail.com
hoo567@outlook.com
```

Example non-matching inputs:

```
foo@gmail.com
johndoe88@hotmail.com
john1976@outlook.com
```

Comment: Why would you use regexes for this?

Comment: Please show examples of ok and not ok input. consider that someone can be aged over 99 too.

Comment: I've included some examples.

Comment: Maybe [`^(?!\w*(?:(?:19|20)\d{2}|(?<!\d)[6-9][0-9](?!\d)|(?<!\d)[0-1][0-9](?!\d))\D*)(?!\D*@)\w+@.*`](https://regex101.com/r/lN7lP4/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is difficult to invert, i.e. to **not** match something.

In your simple case I would just parse an arbitrary long number, and then do the check in code, preferably after converting it to an integer.

But to your question, the following would invert the cases, just or them together

```
(\d)|                            1 digit
([2345]\d)|                      2 digits not starting with 0,1,6,7,8,9
(\d\d\d)|                        3 digits
((1[^9]|2[^0]|[03-9]\d)\d\d)|    4 digits not starting with 19 or 20 
(\d\d\d\d\d*)                    5+ digits
```

Something like this. I'm sure someone can make it prettier.

**EDIT**

Here is the full regex now tested properly with all possible cases I can think of matching your specified criteria, and proper boundary tests (see https://regex101.com/r/sM5aF7/1):

```
(\b|[^\d\s])(\d|[2345]\d|\d{3}|(1[^9]|2[^0]|[03-9]\d)\d\d|\d{5,})(\D*?@|@)
```

Comment: I used your answer before your own edit yesterday and made some changes:


`(\D\d\D*@)|(\D[2345]\d\D*@)|(\D\d\d\d\D*@)|(\D(1[^9]|2[^0]|[03-9]\d)\d\d\D*@)|(\D\d\d\d\d\d+\D*@)`



This gave me the matchs that I was searching for, but maybe I'm still making some mistake here. Your new regex matched on 'johndoe2003@yahoo.com.br' and 'foo_john99@hotmail.com', and these are e-mails that I needed to skip. But still, your answer was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: No match [here](https://regex101.com/r/sM5aF7/2) for 'johndoe2003@yahoo.com.br' and 'foo_john99@hotmail.com'. ;)  If you are satisfied with the solution and think that noone will improve upon the answer, then please accept and maybe upvote.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'm just having problems with regex functions of Oracle SQL. I tried to upvote, but seems I don't have enough rep to do this :\

Comment: Your version works equally fine. PS: Accept (green check mark) works always. For [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you need 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

This regex passes your examples:

```
\D(?![6-9]\d\D)\d{2,3}\D
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/BsrpUK2o4Q).

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/wE3rO5/1) you see that there are problems with the 3 and 2 digit numbers, if I understand the requirements correctly.